# How to use the OpenCV CUDA Fourier Transform

Tags: c++, opencv

Instead of OpenCV's normal `dft`, I'd like to use `cuda::dft`. As a start I tried performing a forward and inverse transform, but the result doesn't look anything like the input. Here's a minimal example using an OpenCV [example image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/samples/data/basketball1.png):

```
// Load 8bit test image (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/samples/data/basketball1.png)
Mat testImg;
testImg = imread("basketball1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

// Convert input to complex float image
Mat_<float> imgReal;
testImg.convertTo(imgReal, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);
Mat imgImag = Mat(imgReal.rows, imgReal.cols, CV_32F, float(0));
vector<Mat> channels;
channels.push_back(imgReal);
channels.push_back(imgImag);
Mat imgComplex;
merge(channels,imgComplex);

imshow("Img real", imgReal);
waitKey(0);

//Perform a Fourier transform
cuda::GpuMat imgGpu, fftGpu;
imgGpu.upload(imgComplex);

cuda::dft(imgGpu, fftGpu, imgGpu.size());

//Performs an inverse Fourier transform
cuda::GpuMat propGpu, convFftGpu;
cuda::dft(fftGpu, propGpu, imgGpu.size(), DFT_REAL_OUTPUT | DFT_SCALE);

Mat output(propGpu);
output.convertTo(output, CV_8U, 255, 0);

imshow("Output", output);
waitKey(0);
```

I played with the flags but `output` never looks anything like input. Using the above code I get as output:

[image]

While it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957671/opencv-gpudft-distorted-image-after-inverse-transform). Apparently, when starting with a complex input image, it's not possible to use the flag `DFT_REAL_OUTPUT`.

Either you do the forward transform with a one channel float input and then you get the same as an output from the inverse transform, or you start with a two channel complex input image and get that type as output. The upside to using a complex input image is that the forward transform delivers the full sized complex field to work with, e.g. perform a convolution (see linked answer for details).

I'll add that in order to obtain an 8bit image from the inverse transform, compute the magnitude yourself like so:

```
Mat output(propGpu);
Mat planes[2];
split(output,planes);
Mat mag;
magnitude(planes[0],planes[1],mag);
mag.convertTo(mag, CV_8U, 255, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To go into Fourier domain using `OpenCV Cuda FFT` and back into the spatial domain, you can simply follow the below example (to learn more, you can refer to [`cufft documentation`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html), on which [`OpenCV Cuda FFT source code`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/cudaarithm/src/arithm.cpp) is based).

```
Mat test_im;
test_im = imread("frame.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// Convert input input to real value type (CV_64F for double precision)
Mat im_real;
test_im.convertTo(im_real, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);

imshow("Input Image", im_real);
waitKey(0);

// Perform The Fourier Transform
cuda::GpuMat in_im_gpu, fft_im;
in_im_gpu.upload(im_real);
cuda::dft(in_im_gpu, fft_im, in_im_gpu.size(), 0);

// Performs an inverse Fourier transform
cuda::GpuMat ifft_im_gpu;
//! int odd_size = imgGpu.size().width % 2;
//! cv::Size dest_size((fftGpu.size().width-1)*2 + (odd_size ? 1 : 0), fftGpu.size().height);
cv::Size dest_size = in_im_gpu.size();
int flag = (DFT_SCALE + DFT_REAL_OUTPUT) | DFT_INVERSE;
cuda::dft(fft_im, ifft_im_gpu, dest_size, flag);

Mat ifft_im(ifft_im_gpu);
ifft_im.convertTo(ifft_im, CV_8U, 255, 0);

imshow("Inverse FFT", ifft_im);
waitKey(0);
```